# Callback not getting called while using async.series

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following code, where i am calling a callback after my async task is completed:

```
var async = require("async");

function _callback(err, result){
    if(err) console.log('Error Occurred');
    console.log('Callback called');
    console.dir(result);
}

function tasks() {
    console.log('Start executing tasks');
    var tasks = [];
    var result = {};

    tasks.push(function(_callback) {
        console.log('Getting some data');
        _callback(null, result);
    });
    tasks.push(function(_callback) {
        console.log('Second function called');
        _callback(null, result);
    });

    async.series(tasks, function(){
        console.log('All done');
    });
}

tasks();
```

I have checked against the syntax expected in the async library. Code looks similar to me.

Can someone point out whats needs to be changed here.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
var async = require("async");

function _callback(err, result){
    if(err) console.log('Error Occurred');
    console.log('Callback called');
    console.dir(result);
}

function tasks() {
    console.log('Start executing tasks');
    var tasks = [];
    var result = {};

    tasks.push(function(next) {
        console.log('Getting some data');
        next(null, result);
    });
    tasks.push(function(_callback) {
        console.log('Second function called');
        next(null, result);
    });

    async.series(tasks, function(err, result){
        console.log('All done');
        _callback(err, result);
    });
}

tasks();
```

Async gives every single task a callback which you need to call to let async now that this task finished.
After all tasks are finished you can call your callback.
If you want your callback to get called after every single task is finished just add before every
`next(null, result)` also an `_callback(null, result)`
The reason that wouldn't work on your implementation is that you overwrite the global _callback method with the argument that has the same name.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Hi Ben. I got the issue with `_callback()` overriding global callback. I dont understand how to use `next()`. Is that i have to rename my `_callback()`.

Comment: You just call it `next` by convention. You could call it whatever you want. I think they chose `next` because when you call it, it means that your task is done and it can do the next task.

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did the code I posted work for you and if so, what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I am expecting `console.log('Callback called');` to be called for each task completion. That doesnt happen.

Comment: Right, with the code I posted it will be called once. After ALL tasked finished successful.
So it should log to the console `All Done` and right afterwards `Callback called`.
If you want it to be called after each task is completed you need to look for the two `next(null, result)` in my example and add before them `_callback(null, result)` then it will be called three times (after each task and at the very end). If you don't want it to get called at the end remove the `_callback(err, result)` after the `console.log('All done')`
Hope that makes it a little clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72586/discussion-between-jsbisht-and-ben-a).

Answer (score 1):

As it stands in your code right now, the `_callback` function you define above should never get called, as the `_callback` in the tasks functions is scope to the one passed by `async`.

```
// this will never get called
function _callback(err, result){
    if(err) console.log('Error Occurred');
    console.log('Callback called');
    console.dir(result);
}

function tasks() {
    console.log('Start executing tasks');
    var tasks = [];

    tasks.push(function(_callback) { // the _callback here overrides the one above for this closure
        console.log('Getting some data');
        _callback(null, result);
    });
    // ... more tasks

    async.series(tasks, function(){
        console.log('All done');
    });
}
```

If you want to reuse the logic in your `_callback` function, I'd recommend passing it the `async` callback as a parameter:

```
// rename some functions to avoid silly js scoping mysteries
function myCallback(err, result, asyncCallback){
    // shared logic here
    if(err) console.log('Error Occurred');
    console.log('Callback called');
    console.dir(result);

    asyncCallback(null, result);
}

// ...

tasks.push(function(asyncCallback) { // the _callback here overrides the one above for this closure
    console.log('Getting some data');
    myCallback(null, result, asyncCallback);
});
// ... more tasks
```

`async` wants its callback to be called so it knows when to continue, but that doesn't mean you can't intercept it with your own handlers :P.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function call to _callback.  You could simplify it like this.

```
var async = require("async");

function doSomeLogic(item, callback) {
    console.log(item);
    callback(null, item + 2);
}

function tasks() {
    console.log('Start executing tasks');
    var tasks = [];
    var result = {};

    tasks.push(function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    });

    tasks.push(function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    });


    async.series(tasks, function(error, results) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(results);
        console.log('All done');
    });
}

tasks();
```

Comment: i made a slight edit, give it a try again.  it works locally for me.  could you explain more why its not working?

Comment: I tried the updated code as well. `callback` is not getting called. Not sure how `doSomeLogic` would be invoked here.

Comment: I am expecting `console.log('Callback called');` to be called for each task completion. That doesnt happen.